# Login page doesn't show in django all-auth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am having a problem with django allauth login page. I was able to complete the tutorial [django all-auth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), however I encountered a problem with the login page when I tried `http://localhost/accounts/login/` nothing is showing but only a blank page.

And the tutorial does not show how to create the login page, so I guess that is the last step I should be working on.

What I did until now is this,

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.sites',
   'allauth',
   'allauth.account',
   'allauth.socialaccount',
   'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {'google': {'SCOPE': ['email'],
     'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}
 }
}

# Django all auth settings
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Also I already added a social application in the Django admin and it's required fields.

Thank you soo much, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: what you did till now? post your code

Comment: Which port is runserver using? Have you tried: http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off of [@bharat's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801008/2105769) and for others stumbling across this post trying to figure out why nothing is being displayed...

django-allauth comes with templates that have all of the content that you already need and even a few templates that you may have not added yourself. But, as comes with the templates, comes the project-owners project structure.

If you want all of your django-allauth pages to use the content that it comes with, you will need to copy and paste the templates into your template folder and then update them to work with your project structure...

So, you will need to do to the typical installation process and then add all of the templates as well. I just can't find this documented anywhere. You can see all of the templates [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates).

**EDIT:** If you look closely at the top of the templates page it says 'Overridable templates' which clearly answers the issue that I had for hours. But, if you missed that as I did. There's your issue.

If you're not planning on using the [django-allauth views](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html) though, you don't have to. You can totally implement social-authentication without using all of the views. So, it's up to you... But, once you implement them you will realize that it does save you an incredible amount of time in setting your future projects up. It's just a matter of getting it working the first time.

There are likely a couple of things you will have to change in the templates for everything to work.

1. Update the `<title>` block that is `{% block head_title %}`.
2. Update the `{% block content %}` to whatever you call your body block.
3. Import django-crispy-forms with `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}`.
4. Make all of your forms crispy.

If you're using all of the django-allauth views. Chances are you want an account view so you will need to create that as well because that does not come in the views.

But, you can totally just use the same pattern that django-allauth does and create something like `accounts/<username>/`

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at this GitHub Repo would help you to create a login page:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html.

You should also ensure that the login page has appropriate url-mappings on urls.py file.

Hope, that helps.